# kotlin - resolve error in DataBindingUtil.setContentView()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am facing problem in `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()`. It is showing the following error.

> [Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  setContentView(p0: Activity, p1: Int): T!
>       Please specify it explicitly.

**MY Code :**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_home) var binding = 
    DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home) 
}
```

Anyone help me resolve this error. I have done clean and `Rebuild(Invalidate and Restart)` also.

Please let me know any other suggestion.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
        var binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home)
......
       }`

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     //set contentView
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
var binding : ActivityHomeBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home)
```

`DataBindingUtil.setContentView` is returning the binding of the particular layout file passed in as parameter.

Comment: This is not the correct answer, please refer my answer.

Comment: @Ishaan Its correct or not that will decide by users who is getting error and solved mine or yours solutions.

Comment: A thousand apologies, I'd just started with data binding that time. The point to notice for beginners is the name "ActivityHomeBinding" which is derived from your layout name which in the above case is "activity_home" hence the binding class. The binding is a auto-generated class.

Answer (score 1):

Create a binding object like this.

```
 val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
        this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

You have to mention the **Activity Binding type**. I have the Main activity so the binding type is `ActivityMainBinding`. This is what you have missed.

**It should be like this:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
  var binding : ActivityMainBinding = 
  DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable binding in view's XML file as well, by simply wrapping all the ui in layout tag.

Just go to the file: `R.layout.activity_home`

It should look like the following code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.SurveyListActivity">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

by the way Clean build , invalid and restart is not the only solution in Android studio #JustKidding :)

Regarding the error that you are facing, you actually need to specify the View:

`val listViewEmployees = findViewById(R.id.listViewEmployees)`

as ListView to

`val listViewEmployees = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listViewEmployees)`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to :

```
    var binding : ActivityMainBinding = 
    DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_home)
```

Then make "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart"

Answer (score 0):

In the layout file of your project i.e. `ativity_home.xml` make sure that you have enclosed your layout may it be a constraint, linear, relative, etc. in the `<layout>` tag.
**Also, add all the namespaces to the layout tag**.

For example, change

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.auth.SignUpActivity">
```

to

```
<layout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>

<data>
.
.
.
<data/>

<Scroll View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.auth.SignUpActivity">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this@MainActivity, R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

In Kotlin everything seems weird initially. Refer the above code to resolve the issue, even then if the error doesn't resolve, checkout the type casting below.

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this@MainActivity, R.layout.activity_main)
```

FYI: The name ActivityMainBinding comes from the name of your layout xml. If it's named "activity_main" it will be "ActivityMainBinding"